# Как синхронизировать миграции с базой?

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста, я загрузил в базу данные с дампа и у меня в базе уже есть поля, но при `manage.py makemigrations` мне пишет что нужно создать их, как можно синхронизировать базу и миграции, чтобы я не плодил новые миграции и не пушил всё в гит?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как случилось что у вас в БД есть поля, о которых django не знает, и считает, что нужны миграции для их создания. Полностью ли структура этой конкретной БД соответствует состоянию моделей в коде?  Или есть отличия? Если создаете новую БД с нуля, то состояние миграций и кода друг другу соответствуют?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA сделал базу MySQL на докере, туда загрузил дамп, после обычного migrate с другими моделями проблем нет. При makemigration пишет что поля были изменены, только в одной модели. Если дальше просто сделать миграции то всё хорошо, но тогда возникает другой вопрос, а не будет ли ошибок у других когда они попробуют запустить эти же миграции

Answer (score 1):

В ответ на вопрос, вам необходимо использовать

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```

После того как выполнили `makemigrations`

Comment: А во-вторых, по сути ответа, как `makemigrations` + `migrate` поможет решить проблему автору вопроса? У него makemigrations создает миграции с изменениями, которые уже в БД. `migrate` в таком случае вообще не пройдет.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Абсолютно согласен, после чтения [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#the-commands). Смотреть второй абзац. Моя ошибка и не верное использование. Признаю

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA а по второму комментарию, не соглашусь. Не вижу проблем накатывать изменения в БД вручную. Конфликты полей возможны, но это не верное составление моделей, как таковых

Comment: После `makemigrations` создаются миграции, которых быть не должно. Далее, эти миграции  нельзя выполнить (`migrate` просто закончится с ошибкой). Объясните, как то, что вы написали, помогает решить проблему автора? Я не понимаю.